# Edit 3d ticks position

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I would draw ticks every Friday and Sunday **at the end of day**

Actually I'm using this function that shows ticks every 7 days **at midnight** ( 00:00:00 )

```
rectContainer
.append("g")
.call(axisBottom(this.timeScale))
```

for example for sunday It show sunday at 00:00:00 I would show tick at 23:59:59 instead ( or 00:00:00 of the next day )

[image]

How can I customize tick position to stick on this rule ?

should  be aligned on red line

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining your timeScale at the start of the day use the dates you have and parse it adding the time you wish, for example:

`new Date("2022-09-29T23:59")`

and so, the ticks will show where you want.